# Java generics puzzler with generic static factory

Tags: java, generics

I recently started writing a generic object mapper for a project and ran into something I don't quite understand. Given the following:

```
public class G<X> {
  public G(Class<X> c) { }

  public void m(X x) { }

  public static <T> G<T> create(Class<T> c) {
    return new G<T>(c);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = ""; // irrelevant!
    G<?> t = create(o.getClass());
    t.m(o);
  }
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
m(capture#402 of ?) in G<capture#402 of ?> cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to properly cast `t` to make this compile. What am I missing? Using JDK 1.6.

**EDIT**:

This is **not** an academic question. I'm trying to write a mapper from hibernate objects to their corresponding DTO to be passed around in the REST layer. The assumption is that for each  ORM object `Foo`, there might exist a class `FooDTO` that has a constructor that takes an instance of `Foo` as a parameter. The generic class that maps `Foo` to `FooDTO` will encapsulate this assumption and throw appropriate exceptions if `FooDTO` doesn't exist or doesn't have the proper constructor:

```
class Mapper<Foo,FooDTO> {
  private final Constructor<FooDTO> dtoConstructor;
  Mapper(Class<Foo> fooClass, Class<FooDTO> fooDTOClass){
    // find the constructor of FooDTO or throw ...
  }
  public FooDTO map(Foo f){
    return dtoConstructor.newInstance(f);
  }
  // this factory is for convenience when we don't know the type of FooDTO:
  public static Mapper<X,Object> create(Class<X> fromClass){
    Class<Object> dtoClass = // ... find it
    return new Mapper<X,Object>(fromClass,dtoClass);
  }
}
```

This seems to break if I pass a generic object class to `create`.

Note that my actual implementation has all `FooDTO` classes extends from a generic super class, i.e., the signature of `Mapper` is actually something like `Mapper<Foo,DTO<Foo>>`. I don't think that's relevant here.

**EDIT 2**:

Actually the suggestion of changing the line `G<?> t = create(o.getClass());` to `G<Object> t = (G<Object>) create(o.getClass());` worked in this context.

Unfortunately I didn't realize that the fact that my class is more complex actually has an impact. Here's a more complete example (I apologize for the piecemeal question):

```
public class Y<T> {
}

public class G<X, Z extends Y<X>> {
  public G(Class<X> c, Class<Z> s) {
  }

  public void m(X x) {
  }

  public static <T, S extends Y<T>> G<T, S> create(Class<T> c) {
    Class<S> s = null; // find this via some reflection magic
    return new G<T, S>(c, s);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = ""; // irrelevant!
    G<? extends Object, Y<? extends Object>> t = create(o.getClass());
    t.m(o);
  }
}
```

In this case the object `Class<S>` is created using reflection and some conventional location for objects of that type. That part works fine and should be irrelevant to this discussion. The error I am getting now is the following:

```
inconvertible types
found   : G<capture#155 of ? extends java.lang.Object,Y<capture#155 of ? extends java.lang.Object>>
required: G<java.lang.Object,Y<java.lang.Object>>
```

And if I change the incriminated line to:

```
G<Object, Y<Object>> t = (G<Object, Y<Object>>) create(o.getClass());
```

I get a similar error:

```
java: inconvertible types
required: G<java.lang.Object,Y<java.lang.Object>>
found:    G<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object,Y<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object>>
```

Once again, I apologize for the piecemeal information. I am sorting through this while I am writing.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let me add some more comments.

Comment: Try it with G<? extends Object>. See [the docs for getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29)

Comment: @sinelaw no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a consumer.  However, the following seems to compile (in Eclipse).

```
public static class G<X, Z extends Y<X>> {
    public G(Class<? extends X> c, Class<Z> s) {}
    public void m(X x) {}
    public static <T, S extends Y<T>> G<T, S> create(Class<? extends T> c) {
        Class<S> s = null; // find this via some reflection magic
        return new G<T, S>(c, s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = ""; // irrelevant!
        create(o.getClass()).m(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this changes the class entirely. Presumably the only reason that the constructor took `Class<X>` is probably because it's important that the `x` passed to `.m()` is an instance of this class. If you change it to `Class<? extends X>` then this no longer holds.

Comment: Accepting because in my case this works perfectly. If I find a case in which it breaks I'll update my question.

Comment: @newacct, you're right that this changes the class `G`, but think about it: you can always pass something of a type that extends `X` to `m` anyway.  We're giving that type a wildcard name

Comment: @JudgeMental: I am saying that `x` is not an instance of that class. I mean, what's the point of passing class `c` of type `Class<X>` into the constructor of `G`? The OP's code doesn't show any code in the class, so taken literally we can just remove that parameter.  But one would guess that there's some requirement the class `c` matches the first type argument of `G`. In particular, the type `X` is used in one other place: the type of parameter `x` in method `m`. So it's reasonable to imagine that there's some requirement that `x` in `m` must be an instance of `c`.

Comment: Point taken.  In practice the `c` parameter is likely to come from `getClass()` called on the argument of `m()`, but there is no compiler guarantee of that in this rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You have passed the `Class` object from [the `getClass()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29), which returns a `Class<?>`, meaning that you had to declare `t` to be a `G<?>`.

You cannot call a method with a generic type parameter when the generic type parameter of the variable is a wildcard.  The compiler doesn't know which specific class the wildcard really is, so it cannot guarantee type safety when such a method is called.  It's the same reason that `add` can't be called on a `List<?>`.

To get this to compile, you must use a class literal, to avoid having a `Class<?>`, and declare `t` not to have a wildcard.

```
G<Object> t = create(Object.class);
```

Then

```
t.mo(o);
```

will compile.

Comment: What if I don't know the type and I only have a reference to an object? That's my whole problem right there. If I pass `Object.class` I lose all the runtime type information.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a `G<Object>` and then assigning it to a variable of type `G<?>`. The method invoked takes a variable of the generic type, which won't take anything for `<?>`. If you change the variable to `G<Object>` it will work.

Comment: I don't think simply changing `G<?>` to `G<Object>` compiles. Because of the way `G`'s constructor is written, `create(o.getClass())` is creating a `G<? extends Object>`.

Comment: Actually that worked. I have a follow up though. Changing my SO.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are specifying `G<?>`, javac is expecting to figure out what the generics are (what classes do they represent). Changing the statement to `G t = create(o.getClass());` fixes the errors.

`capture` errors generally mean that the compiler is unable to figure out the classes...

Its not really clear what you are trying to do... Perhaps that information would be useful in helping you more...

Comment: Removing the generics does not fix the problem, it just sweeps it under the rug. Yes, the compiler is unable to figure out the type, but removing the generics removes generic type safety, so the compiler isn't even given the chance.